# How to read N matrixes from the keyboard

Tags: matlab, variables, loops, matrix

I need to save N matrixes from the user. I already save the matrix asking for how many rows and columns and iterate N times, but my question is how can I save the name of the N matrix.

Example

matrix1 = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]

matrix2 = [7 8 9; 14 15 16]

.

.

.

matrixN = [0 0 0; 0 0 0]

This is the code I have:

```
for k = 1:nClases
    for i = 1:m(i)
        for j = 1:n(i)
            str = ['Ingresa elemento en fila ' num2str(i) ', columna ' num2str(j) ' de clase' num2str(k) ': ' ]; 
            clase(i,j) = input(str);
            eval(sprintf('clase%d = [1:k]', k));
        end 
    end 
end
```

`k` is the number of matrix I need.

`m` is the rows.

`n` is the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you want the user to input N matrices and don't know how to save the matrices with a given name.

You can try the following:

After a given matrix is filled out, you can do:

```
Matrix{k} = clase;
```

This will come after the `i` and `j` loops end.

At the end, you will have a cell array of matrices. To access the second one, you can just type `Matrix{2}`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is create a variable name for each incrementing matrix, matrix_k.  The following line will return a string "filename" with the string "matrix" followed by the matrix number k:

```
filename = genvarname(['matrix' num2str(k)]);
```

You can then save the matrix with the following:

```
save(filename, 'matrix');
```

If you would like to simply assign the value of each new matrix to a  new variable name, you could instead use the following:

```
eval(['matrix' num2str(k) '=' num2str(matrix)])
```

which will create a variable "matrix_k" and assign the current value of matrix to it.